# Error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int

Tags: c++

QT Creator.
Есть класс:

```
class Option: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    static int getSizeHistory();
    Option();
    ~Option();

private:
    static int sizeHistory;
};
```

Его реализация в option.cpp.
С другого класса я вызываю его статический метод:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
    Option::getSizeHistory();
}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку:

> mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int **cdecl Option::getSizeHistory(void)" (?getSizeHistory@Option@@SAHXZ) referenced in function "private: void** thiscall MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered(void)" (?on_actionOpen_triggered@MainWindow@@AAEXXZ)

Comment: >Его реализация в option.cpp

Код option.cpp в студию. И он вообще линкуется в проекте?

Comment: Файл "option.cpp" в проект добавлен.
Вот реализация этого метода:

int Option::getSizeHistory()
{
    return Option::sizeHistory;
}

Comment: @vaddemgen: добавлен — это хорошо. А всё же, он линкуется? Может, вы его как-то не так добавили. Или например нахимичили с namespace'ами. Или ещё что-нибудь. Выложите куда-нибудь _весь_ файл, в приведённом фрагменте проблем не видно.

Comment: так и есть. забыл инициализировать статический член класса. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вы забыли инициализировать статический член класса перед его использованием (попробуйте static int sizeHistory = 0;)